"Given enough eyes, all bugs are shallow". Did this idea exist before Eric Raymond wrote "The Cathedral and the Bazaar"?
From What success really looks like in open source | by Nadia Asparouhova | Medium:

When we talk about successful open source projects, we imagine big, thriving, participatory communities, where many people share the burden of contribution.
Where did this idea come from?
Open source as a community model can be traced back to nearly 20 years ago, when Eric Raymond wrote an essay called “The Cathedral and the Bazaar”, outlining two models for software development.
The essay centers around a then-new software project, Linux, as a “subversive” example of how software can be built more openly, a “great babbling bazaar of differing agendas and approaches” (Bazaars) rather than “small bands of mages working in splendid isolation”
(Cathedrals).
Raymond believed Bazaars were a more resilient and sustainable approach to software development. More people = more resources. To describe this, Raymond coined the famous line, “Given enough eyes, all bugs are shallow”, which he dubbed “Linus’s Law”.

This gives me an impression that before he wrote this, there was no association between making a free software and having a big, thriving, participatory communities, where many people share the burden of contribution. Is that correct?
